# Графические узлы и их связи

Tags: c#

Как лучше реализовать графические узлы (ноды)? Какими средствами их отрисовывать? Как лучше осуществлять связи между узлами?

Сейчас отрисовываю узлы на Panel с помошью DrawRectangle в событии Paint. Приложение WinForms.

Пример графических узлов взял с сайта mynodes.net

[image]

Comment: какими классами у вас эти ноды и связи описываются? в чем собираетесь рисовать WinForms, Wpf или еще что-то?

Comment: Классов для нод и связей не делал. Ищу верное решение чтобы не переделывать. Рисую на WinForms.

Comment: То, что вы рисуете, это не «графические узлы», это просто прямоугольники с текстом и соединяющие их стрелки. Эти прямоугольники при этом являются графическим _представлением_ узлов какого-то графа.

Comment: Так я и ищу правильное решение

Comment: @VladD ну, формально конечно, можно сделать графическую тулзу способную отображать абстрактную ноду с ее связями. Хотя для этого тоже понадобится абстрактная модель. Не знаю даже что сложнее =)

Comment: @ComradeKolin начать с модели того, что вы собираетесь таким образом отображать. А дальше уже можно думать как это нарисовать